# Is it possible to disable color highlighting in css-mode?

Tags: terminal-emacs, colors, css

I'm using Emacs 26.1 in the terminal (`emacs -nw`).

When using `css-mode`, strings representing colors seem to be automatically highlighted. I don't find this feature useful, and further, the colors chosen often make the text illegible.

Is there a way to disable this while keeping CSS syntax highlighting and formatting?

[image]

Comment: Just try `M-x font-lock-mode` to toggle `font-lock` off. If you like the effect to be permanent you can add `(add-hook 'css-mode-hook (lambda () (font-lock-mode -1)))` to your init file. Not yet posted as an answer since I did not test it.

Comment: @Tobias, thanks, though that appears to disable the syntax highlighting as well.

Comment: Now I know what you mean! You can switch off `css-fontify-colors` in `M-x customize-option css-fontify-colors`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can switch off `css-fontify-colors` in the customization buffer that opens on <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `css-fontify-colors` <kbd>RET</kbd>.